# Advantage of Jenkins Master/Slave architecture?

Tags: jenkins

I am reading about the `Jenkins Master/Slave architecture` and how to configure it from [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines) and as I am going down the page I am wondering why should I do it, what benefit I can achieve through it.

I searched similar questions and reached [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580543/jenkins-master-slave-configuration) but still not convinced about the same.

Can anyone explain me, what all benefits I can achieve with the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have only a few jobs to run on the same platform, having only a Jenkins master to build these jobs is OK.

But if you have hundreds jobs running on different platform (Linux, Windows, 32/64 bits), it's better to use Jenkins slave.

You can affect some labels per slave to sort them by OS, platform, ...

Your Jenkins slaves can run on a VM or on a Docker image.

I think you can find a lot of information on Stackoverflow.

Personally, I prefer the solution with a Jenkins server and some Jenkins slaves. On the master, I set the number of executors to 0 in order to have good performance with the Jenkins application. All the jobs run on  slaves.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Hello, I am interested in this topic and I would kindly ask if you can expand on this a bit. My app runs on a single platform so I don't need to test different distributions. In this case, is it still worth configuring a Jenkins slave? Is there any gain from the resource perspective? I have 4 executors on my master node, and it's doing fine but sometime the app is laggy. I wonder if I create a slave on the same machine, and set 2/2 execturos, would I gain any speed?

Comment: @Vivere If you install the slave on the same machine, your Jenkins app will slow down. It's better to configure the slaves on a new VM/machine so Jenkins master will be faster.