# Github deploy key on Jenkins Master/Slave Architecture

Tags: git, github, jenkins, continuous-deployment, master-slave

I am working with a private repository from my organization and the [Deploy key](http://blogs.perficient.com/delivery/blog/2014/03/26/using-git-deploy-key-in-jenkins-written-by-tom-tang/) approach for authentication.[This](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys) [tutorials](https://gist.github.com/victorborda/2871029) for deploy key configuration are pretty straight forward. It's just there is one confusion I have. The slave instances [don't actually have jenkins installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580543/jenkins-master-slave-configuration), so is not possible to login as `sudo -u jenkins` in the slave. In the other side, the job doesn't actually run on master but in the slave instance, so the deploy key would have to be a public key generated from the slave. But then when I try to set up the job in the jenkins server it says `Host key verification failed` I'm guessing because it doesn't recognize the key from the master server.

What am I missing? I'm so confused.

[image]

**EDIT:**

I thought maybe the master didn't recognize that the slave was going to be the one running this job and gives the error because is trying to authenticate from its own public key. So I decided to go ahead and run the job anyways. And now I'm even more confused.. the job is running successfully but still gives a `timeout` (I don't know if it's related or not, still searching). Any thoughts?

```
Started by user User
Building remotely on android-slave (android) in workspace /home/ubuntu/workspace/android-repo
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:Organization/Repo-Droid.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:Organization/Repo-Droid.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:Organization/Repo-Droid.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 32e37279cb794b9f8eebbdf5f0d47671eea522c7 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 32e37279cb794b9f8eebbdf5f0d47671eea522c7
 > git rev-list 32e37279cb794b9f8eebbdf5f0d47671eea522c7 # timeout=10
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

I verified this is not actually an error, even though I'd still like to know what this `#timeout=10` is. I checked the workspace folder in the jobs' main page and I see the project cloned successfully. I also added a `gradle clean` command to the job configuration to be sure it compiles ok. Everything looks good.

**NOTE:** I still get the `Host key verification failed` error in the job configuration but as I said above is probably because the master server is trying to match the repository's deploy key with its own public key, and not the slave's public key. So when I ignored that error and tried to build the job it does it successfully because it's configured to always run on the slave machine.